# Problema com Keyframe dentro do @media no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mobile, css-animations

Bom dia

Estou encontrando a seguinte dificuldade na edição de um código mobile no css do wordpress, fiz uma animação com o keyframe no desktop com o código abaixo, porém chegou a hora de colocar essa mesma animação adaptada para o mobile. O problema é que quando coloco esse bloco de código dentro do @media o wordpress acusa erro, já tentei retirar o mesmo do @media e mudar o nome da classe porém sem sucesso. Desde já agradeço.
segue as imagens com o erro apresentado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
 #unidade-movel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 97px;
    animation: unidade-movel 10s infinite ;
}

@keyframes unidade-movel {
0% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 0%;
}

10% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 10%;
}
20% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20%;
}
30% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 30%;
}
40% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 40%;
}
45% {
    top: 130px;
    left: 45%;
}
50% {
    top: 150px;
    left: 40%;
}
60% {
    top: 150px;
    left: 25%;
}
70% {
    top: 180px;
    left: 20%;
}
80% {
    top: 205px;
    left: 20%;
}
90% {
    top: 280px;
    left: 20%;
}
100% {
    top: 280px;
    left: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: Cara eu testei seu código aqui, e da parte do CSS não deu erro algum... Funcionou perfeitamente... Se deu algum erro tente colocar na pergunta qual foi o erro que apresentou. Ou um link como o erro, ou a mensagem de erro que aparece etc... Algo que ajude a te responder

Comment: por gentileza  @hugocsl coloquei duas imagens na pergunta, desde já agradeço!

Comment: Seu erro é que está faltando um `}` na linha 558. Isso é pq vc abriu o `@media ... 767px... {` mas não fechou `}` ficou faltando essas chaves antes de começar o @keyframes

Comment: entendi sua dica, porém eu já fiz dessa forma, eu já coloquei o código do keyframe depois de fechar o media, eu fiz uma pesquisa antes de postar aqui que o media não aceitava o keyframe dentro dele. Quando faço dessa forma ele não apresenta erro, mas neste modo mesmo eu colocando um keyframes unidade-movel-mobile não reconhece, quando inspeciono o código não aparece o keyframe do mobile somente do desk

Comment: Pelo que entendi vc tem duas animações uma para mobile e outra para desk, basta trocar o animation-name do elemento dentro do @media que vc quer com o nome da animação correspondente, isso pelo que eu entendi do seu comentário.... Se vc ainda estiver na dúvida Cria outra pergunta, ou edite essa, e coloca um exemplo simplificado e pergunta como vc alterna `@keyframes` diferentes dependendo do tamanho da tela.... Ai te dou uma força

Comment: @hugocsl desculpa o incomodo mas era exatamente isso o que estava acontecendo, o animation name estava com o nome do desk. Fiz a troca e resolveu o problema! Problema resolvido, mais uma vez muito obrigado!

Comment: Sem problemas meu caro, que bom que resolveu. Outra dica e sempre que for perguntar aqui no site tentar dar o máximo de detalhe possível, e sempre colocar todo o código referente ao problema, ou a comunidade vai acabar fechando sua pergunta... Sucesso ai, abs